# Map a navigation property to a instance var as Foreign key

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, database-design, entity-relationship

I'm developing an Entity Framework Code First (v. 4.4.0.0) C# library with .Net Framework 4.0.

I don't know how to set zero-to-one relationship. My model is the following:

A `Talk` can be created by only one user (`StarterUserId`).
A `Talk` can have only one recipient user (`RecepientUserId`) or only one group (`RecipientGroupId`). 
**Note**: That means that `RecepientUserId` is null if `RecipientGroupId`is not null; or `RecepientUserId` is not null if `RecipientGroupId`is null.

A `user` can be a recipient of zero or n `Talks`, but a `group` can have zero or one `Talk`.

This is **Talk** class:

```
[DataContract]
public class Talk
{
    [DataMember]
    public int TalkId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int StarterUserId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int? RecipientUserId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [ForeignKey("RecipientGroup")]
    public int? RecipientGroupId { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateUtcStarted { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string DateStarted
    {
        get
        {
            return DateUtcStarted.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
        }
        set
        {
            DateUtcStarted = DateTime.Parse(value);
        }
    }

    public User StarterUser { get; set; }
    public User RecipientUser { get; set; }

    public Group RecipientGroup { get; set; }
}
```

With this **TalkConfiguration** class:

```
class TalkConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Talk>
{
    public TalkConfiguration()
    {
        Property(t => t.StarterUserId).IsRequired();
        Property(t => t.RecipientUserId).IsOptional();
        Property(t => t.RecipientGroupId).IsOptional();
        Property(t => t.DateUtcStarted).IsRequired();

        Ignore(t => t.DateStarted);

        HasRequired(t => t.StarterUser).
            WithMany(u => u.TalksStarted).
            HasForeignKey(t => t.StarterUserId);
        HasOptional(t => t.RecipientUser).
            WithMany(u => u.InTalks).
            HasForeignKey(t => t.RecipientUserId);

        HasOptional(t => t.RecipientGroup).WithOptionalDependent(g => g.GroupTalk);
    }
}
```

And this is the `Group` class:

```
[DataContract]
public class Group
{
    [DataMember]
    public int GroupId { get; set; }

    [ ... ]

    public Talk GroupTalk { get; set; }
}
```

And the `GroupConfiguration` class:

```
class GroupConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Group>
{
    public GroupConfiguration()
    {
        [ ... ] // Nothing related to GroupTalk
    }
}
```

With these classes and configurations I get this `Talk` table at database:

[image]

I want to make `Talk.RecipientGroupId` as a **FOREIGN KEY** to `Group.GroupId`. But this model creates another column, `Talk.RecipientGroup_GroupId` as **FOREIGN KEY** to `Group.GroupId`. And, I don't want that.

**How can I do it?**

Answer (score 1):

Optional:optional one-to-one relationships are mapped as independent associations, not as foreign key associations which means that you can't have a foreign key property in your model class. That's why you can't chain `HasForeignKey` after `WithOptionalDependent`. And I'm pretty sure that the `[ForeignKey]` attribute on `RecipientGroupId` is simply ignored and EF considers `RecipientGroupId` as an ordinary scalar property with no relationship purpose.

In the database schema itself the relationship has a foreign key. That's the one you are seeing with an autogenerated default name: `RecipientGroup_GroupId`. But it's not supported to map this foreign key to a property. However, I think you can rename the column using `MapKey`

```
HasOptional(t => t.RecipientGroup)
    .WithOptionalDependent(g => g.GroupTalk)
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("RecipientGroupId"));
```

If you do that you *must* remove the `RecipientGroupId` property from the `Talk` class, otherwise EF will complain about two conflicting columns with the same name.

I believe, optional:optional are the only one-to-one relationships that are independent associations, all other are foreign key associations where the foreign key property is the primary key property at the same time (according to Arthur Vickers' answer at the bottom of [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/aed3b3f5-c150-4131-a686-1bf547a68804/onetoone-associations-and-identity-column?forum=adonetefx)). With optional:optional relationships this would be impossible because a primary key property cannot be nullable.

Since your `RecipientGroupId` has a `[DataMember]` attribute it looks that you want to transmit the value over some service boundary and therefore need the foreign key as property value for some reason. In this case the workaround that I would choose is mapping the `Talk<->Group` relationship as one-to-many relationship with either no navigation property in the `Group` class at all (mapping it with a parameterless `WithMany()` call then) or with a collection navigation property and ensure then in business logic that this collection cannot contain more than one element.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure what I'm doing. I want to represent that a talk can have zero or one group; and maybe, that optional:optional, doesn't represent that.

Comment: @VansFannel: If you also want to represent that a `Group` can only participate in one talk or no talk at all your intent to map this as optional:optional is fine. However, it just isn't supported by EF to expose a foreign key as property in that case. If a `Group` can participate in more than one talk mapping the relationship as one-to-many would be more suited (and it's technically easier to map anyway).