# EF 5 code first optional one to one mapping accessing foreign key fields on the model

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, code-first

This question is basically a repeat of [this question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/da89783a-549f-4a45-8c52-ea40032cec54/ef4-ctp5-code-first-optional-one-to-one-mapping-accessing-foreign-key-fields-on-the-model) regarding EF4 CTP but specific to EF 5.

I have a POCOs set up such that

```
public class ClassPrinciple
{  
    public int ClassPrincipleID { get; set; }

    public virtual ClassDependent ClassDependent{ get; set; }

}
```

and

```
public class ClassDependent
{  
    public int ClassDependentID { get; set; }

    public virtual ClassPrinciple ClassPrinciple{ get; set; }

}
```

in my model builder I create the optional one to one mapping like this

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ClassPrinciple>().HasOptional(p => p.ClassDependent)
                .WithOptionalDependent(s => s.ClassPrinciple);
```

this creates, on the ClassPrinciples table a column called ClassDependent_ClassDependentID .  I would like to be able to reference the data in this column through a property on the ClassPrinciple model but I seem unable to do so.  The web page I linked to at the top of this question states:

> EF in general only supports exposing FK properties on your entities in
>   one:many relationships (unless the FK is also the PK). This is
>   somewhat artificial but a side effect of EF not supporting non-PK
>   unique constraints. We are working on support for unique constraints
>   for EF at the moment but it won't be there in our first RTM of Code
>   First.
>
> Sorry not to have a better answer as there really isn't a workaround
>   at this stage.

Is this still the case or is there a way to resolve this.  I have tried fluent api map to column and data annotations in all sorts of combinations without success.

Comment: I think it's still not supported to map the FK to a class property: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20246947/270591

Answer (score 0):

use this code :

```
public class ClassPrinciple
{  
  public int ClassPrincipleID { get; set; }

  public int ClassDependentId { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey("ClassDependentId")]
  [InverseProperty("ClassPrinciple")]
  public virtual ClassDependent ClassDependent{ get; set; }

}

public class ClassDependent
{  
   public int ClassDependentID { get; set; }

   [InverseProperty("ClassDependent")]
   public virtual ClassPrinciple ClassPrinciple{ get; set; }

 }
```